# weblogic авторизация с Servlet

Tags: java, weblogic

Сделал авторизацию на `Servlet`. Как позже выяснил что `Weblogic` сам может регулировать/блокировать пользователя. Как я могу узнать заблокирован ли текущий пользователь?  Немного погуглил пишут что есть вот такой метод `isLockedOut` но как его использовать так и не понял. 
мой код:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            try {
                String result = getCountLoginAttemp(request, false);
                if (result != null) {
                    out.print(getResultGsonString(false, result));
                    return;
                }
                String j_username = request.getParameter("j_username");
                String j_password = request.getParameter("j_password");

                if (isNullOrEmpty(j_username) || isNullOrEmpty(j_password)) {
                    out.print(getResultGsonString(false, "Не все параметры заполнены"));
                    return;
                }

                if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
                    request.logout();
                }

                request.login(j_username, Crypt.MD5(j_password));

                Users user = userControlLocal.getUserByUName(j_username);
                if (user != null) {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    session.setAttribute(USER, user);
                    out.print(getResultGsonString(true, null));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //UserLockoutManagerRuntimeMBean.isLockedOut("");
                String result = getCountLoginAttemp(request, true);
                if (result == null) {
                    result = "Ошибка авторизации";
                }
                out.print(getResultGsonString(false, result));
                //logger.error("error", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getCountLoginAttemp(HttpServletRequest request, boolean itr) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Integer loginAttempt = (Integer) session.getAttribute("loginCount");
        if (loginAttempt == null) {
            loginAttempt = 1;
        }

        if (loginAttempt > loginAttemptCount - 1) {
            StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();
            err.append("Количество попыток неправильного ввода пароли превысило ")
                    .append(loginAttemptCount)
                    .append(".  Следующая попытка через ");

            Long s = (Long) session.getAttribute("loginTime");
            if (s != null) {
                Long res = new Date().getTime() / 1000 - s;
                if (res > 0 && res < 60 * loginAttemptTime) {
                    return err.append((loginAttemptTime - 1) - (res / 60)).append(" мин ").append(59 - (res % 60)).append(" секунд").toString();
                } else {
                    session.setAttribute("loginTime", null);
                    session.setAttribute("loginCount", 1);
                }
            } else {
                session.setAttribute("loginTime", new Date().getTime() / 1000);
                return err.append(loginAttemptTime).append(" мин").toString();
            }
        } else if (itr) {
            loginAttempt++;
            session.setAttribute("loginCount", loginAttempt);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Если речь о методе `weblogic.management.runtime.UserLockoutManagerRuntimeMBean#isLockedOut(String)` то он врятли будет вам полезен т.к. `UserLockoutManagerRuntimeMBean` используется для управления аккаунтами пользователей WebLogic домена через JMX. В вашем случае, на сколько я понял, реч идет о пользователях в контексте web приложения.

Comment: подскажите как я могу это сделать?

Comment: что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: узнавать из weblogic заблокирован/не заблокирован пользователь

Comment: С одной стороны WebLogic ничего не знает о пользователях вашего приложения, с другой мне кажется странной идея интегрировать ваше приложение с WebLogic доменом на предмет работы с пользователями.
Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону SpringSecurity. [Тут](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/) описан способ блокировки пользователей после нескольких неудачных попыток авторизации: